# Python add pandas.core.series.Series to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm working with an excel from which I want to extract certain information and display it in another excel. Using pandas and openpyxl I was able to get the rows I needed to copy (whos type is "pandas.core.series.Series") but I don't know how to copy just those rows to an excel.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export a pandas.Series to Excel.

```
df.to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet_Name_1")
```

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_excel.html).

Comment: No worries. It'd be great if you can accept the answer as well. [Accept an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)